# Storing and editing app,user and custom settings in a desktop applications

Tags: winforms, app-config, application-settings, settings.settings, settings

I'm building a new version of a windows forms application that is beeing installed on a various range of different pc's. The application is beeing installed by a technician, which are configuring different application, user and other settings during the install. These settings I've been storing in the registry up until now, and at every startup of the application it reads the registry to get the different values. If we need to change any setting in the registry we do that directly in the reg (experienced technicians) or through a reinstall (rookie technicians) of the application.

As I'm now building a new version I'm wondering what's the best pratice for handling these types of settings. I want to move it out of the registry and into some kind og setting, resource, xml file that I can manipulated directly under installation process and also afterwards within the application/or through a helper application that is designed for technicians.

So what's the prefered way to store and edit application and user specific settings for a windows forms application?

The Applicatin is a Win 32 bit VB.Net desktop forms app.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd use the back end.  Create a user table and store whatever preferences you want.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the below question is similar to what you are seeking.

[Save Settings in a .NET Winforms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032492/save-settings-in-a-net-winforms-application).

Answer (score 1):

The best way of having user settings is **XML**.
Visual studio Installer(setup project) has limited options for such operations.
if you use install shield then you might have more access to get setting from xml files.

Answer (score 1):

> So what's the prefered way to store and edit application and user specific settings for a  > windows forms application?

The preferred way to store and edit application and user specific settings for .NET application is to use .NET built-in configuration support - classes and interfaces that  located in System.Configuration namespace.
You can do whatever you want with built-in .NET setup project using custom actions(Installer class)