# Image file not found after deploying an application

Tags: c#

In my C# windows forms application, I have an image that I used some where as part of requirement and I stored it in a folder named Images with in my solution.

But when I deployed it and installed the application on a user machine it threw me an error `specified file not found`

I used my image as follows

```
indexWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Atlas Applications\AtlasPetroleumIndex\CLPetroleumIndex\Images\logo.jpg", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 155, 20, 180, 65).LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
```

Comment: Did you mark the file you added as 'Resource'?

Comment: Did you set the file to copy to the output directory when building the application? Or alternatively add it as a resource?

Comment: No, how do I do that

Comment: did you simply put it in that folder and use it in the code, or does Visual Studio know it exists?

Comment: If its embedded than it can't be copied to the output directory.

Comment: @jason I just created a folder and added an image to it

Answer (score 2):

Create an `Images` folder in your solution in VS, then right click on it and go to `Add -> Add Existing Item`.  Select the image you want, then once it's added to your project right click on the image and go to `Properties` and select `Copy Always` for `Copy to Output Directory`

Comment: should I change anything in build action or keeo it none

Comment: You can probably change it to `Resource`

Comment: @Dev I saw that you had a comment saying that it wasn't compiling, but has since been removed.  Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Actually no, I had the image on a server and used that location. Still not sure how I can make that image resource available

Comment: Did you try removing the directory in your build folder that you manually created and let VS create it? Since Images\Logo.jpg already existed it might be causing conflicts

Comment: Yes, I did remove and actually used an absolute location instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent users from deleting your folder containing the `logo` file, you should definitely add this image to the `Resources` of your `Project`.

You can refer to the MSDN [related page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do so. Your image will then be stored into the `executable file` of your application.

If you are also interested in storing other kind of user information, like general settings, preferences, user logo, etc... I suggest you take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032492/save-settings-in-a-net-winforms-application).