# What is the best practice to handle application's settings between several forms

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best practice to handle application's settings contains in the external INI file between several forms?

Suppose that I have two forms -- `MainForm` and `SettingsForm`. User can open the `SettingsForm` from the `MainForm`. Now I have smth like this:

- On `Load` event of the `SettingsForm` I read application's settings from the file and change the UI appropriately
- On "Save" button press I write new options' values to the file
- On the "SettingsFormClosed" event of the `MainForm` I read the settings from the file again

I think that the last thing is the most terrible in this case. Maybe I should use smth like `SettingsSingleton` or smth like this? What is the best practice to do it in C# and Windows Forms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-user-settings-for-a-net-application

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern). You will need a class which represents settings file, this file is `Observable`. Your `SettingsForm` and `MainForm` are `Observers`. And `SettingsForm` can modify the `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it like this, make a Setting class for storing the values, then create a service class that is responsible for saving and supplying the settings to other objects.
Service is implemented as a singleton and implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
Then in your forms you just have to subscribe to ProperyChanging event from the service.

Example service code:

```
 public sealed class SettingsService : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static Lazy<SettingsService> instance = new Lazy<SettingsService>(() => new SettingsService());

        public static SettingsService Instance
        {
            get { return instance.Value; }
        }

        private Setting settings;
        public Setting Settings
        {
           get
           {
              var clone = settings.Clone();
              return clone;
           }
        }

        private SettingsService()
        {
           //load your settings
        }            

        public void SaveChanges(Setting settings)
        {
           //Do whatever you do to save the changes, and raise the event the   settings changed
           this.settings = settings;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged()
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Settings"));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```