# WinForms Application settings are not assigning

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, application-settings

Under Project > MyProject Properties > Settings I have an application setting named MyDouble with double type, the scope is User, the default value is 1.5.

I tried watching it, stepping through the entire application, and MessageBoxes to display the value. I've now commented out all uses of it excluding where I am trying to set a class (Form1) level variable. That looks like this:

```
    double myDouble = Properties.Settings.Default.MyDouble;
```

The value is always zero. If I MessageBox myDouble or the application setting the result is zero.

Some application settings are working. I called two message boxes in Form1_Shown event. One uses:

```
    Properties.Settings.Default.MyDouble.ToString()
```

and the other uses:

```
    Properties.Settings.Default.MyInt.ToString()
```

The second one output the correct value.

This project is a WinForms application written in C#.
Using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017.
This project's form was copied over from a previous project, but I don't think that could affect it. The value in the previous project was the same. I typed these Application settings by hand. I've rechecked to ensure the spelling is correct. I deleted the setup project to no avail. Cleaned and rebuilt the solution... nada. I also checked the app.config file. I don't see anything wrong. Here it is:

```
    <userSettings>
        <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MyDouble" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1.5</value>
            </setting>
        </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why and/or how to fix this?

Comment: have you checked the scope of the setting?

Comment: @user12345 I did. I updated my question to reflect that it has a User scope. All application settings have user scope.

Comment: When the default value is 1.5 and you get 0.0 then you've successfully saved the setting at least once.  That it is not a value you like, well, that happens.  You can edit the user.config file to patch around the (hopefully temporary) problem.  It is just a bit hard to find back in c:\users\yourname\appdata\local\projectname\blablabla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think: something went wrong.

In Solution Explorer, double-click the `.settings` file. The default name for this file is Settings.settings. In the Settings designer, find the Name (MyDouble) of your setting. Each row represents a single setting.

See: [Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx).

You have:

```
<setting name="MyDouble" serializeAs="String">
```

And you write:

```
double myDouble = Properties.Settings.Default.MyDouble;
```

Convert `String` to `double`...may be it wrong?

See this page: [Managing Application Settings (.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) and this answer: [What is the best way to store user settings for a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394/5275890)

Try this code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyDouble = 1.5;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

and after it try this:

```
var myDouble = Properties.Settings.Default.MyDouble;
```

Comment: The settings.settings file was correct. The other double and integer values also say serialize s string. I have no idea what that means. Honestly, I've never even opened that file until now. The code you offered does fix it. I think somehow I was in a bug of visual studio. I ran your code which, of course, sets a new value, saves it. and now it works. without that code block included. Thanks. I'm selecting this as the correct answer since it did work once I tried forcing the application to overwrite the value and save.